# oneupuploader with jQuery-File-Upload UI

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, multi-upload, oneupuploaderbundle

I'm trying to setup jQuery-File-Upload UI with oneupuploaderBundle on a symfony2 Website.

After a lot of tears, the upload process works as I want,but I can't make the Json response work avec the upload.

I use the PostUploadEvent of the oneupuploaderBundle, And tied a lot of solution to send a corecte jSon response to jQuery-File-Upload UI, but i still have an error message when the file has been uploaded.

In the doc, the ask to send a resonse like this:

```
{"files": [
  {
    "name": "picture1.jpg",
    "size": 902604,
    "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture1.jpg",
    "delete_url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "delete_type": "DELETE"
  }
]}
```

Here is mine :

```
{"files": [ 
    { 
    "url": "\/ishowpro-cms\/web\/app_dev.php\/library\/file\/image\/originals\/51dbd9a13a065-screen-shot-mini.png",     
    "thumbnail_url": "\/ishowpro-cms\/web\/app_dev.php\/library\/file\/image\/thumbnails\/51dbd9a13a065-screen-shot-mini.png", 
    "name": "screen-shot-mini.png", 
    "type": "image/png", 
    "size": 1192, 
    "delete_url": "http://nourltodelete.com", 
    delete_type: "DELETE" 
    } 
] }
```

The URls are OK.
I tried to return the response with

```
return new JsonResponse($jsonResponse);
```

with the Normal response object and json headers, I tried to create an entity and serialize it :

```
$responseObjectFile = new JqUploaderFile();
$responseObjectFile->setName();
$responseObjectFile->setSize();
$responseObjectFile->setUrl();
$responseObjectFile->setThumbnail_url();
$responseObjectFile->setDelete_url($this->router->generate('show_image_link', array('slug'=>$file->getSlug(), 'extension'=>$file->getExtension(), 'size'=>'originals'), true));
$responseObjectFile->setDelete_type("DELETE");  


//create serializer to encode Entity
$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
$normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($responseObjectFile, 'json');


//add entity in array and unserilize it....
$responseCode = array('files'=>array($jsonContent) );
```

And also to use the $event->getRequest(); of the object. 
But nothing works.

Is their someone who can help me please ? 
Thank you in advance.

---

Here is the complete file

```
<?php

namespace Reyner\Ishowpro\LibraryBundle\Upload;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostUploadEvent;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PreUploadEvent;
use Reyner\Ishowpro\LibraryBundle\Tools\Tools;

use Reyner\Ishowpro\LibraryBundle\Entity\Folder;
use Reyner\Ishowpro\LibraryBundle\Entity\File;
use Reyner\Ishowpro\LibraryBundle\Entity\JqUploaderFile;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File as sfFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;

use Gaufrette\File as GaufretteFile;


class UploadListener
{
    private $doctrine;
    private $logger;
    private $router;


    public function __construct($doctrine, $logger, \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router $router)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->logger = $logger;  
        $this->router = $router;
    }


    public function onPreUpload(PreUploadEvent $event)
    {           
        $file = $event->getFile();

    }
    public function onUpload(PostUploadEvent $event)
        {
            $this->logger->info('----------------------------------------------------');
            $this->logger->info('------------------    service begin ----------------------');


            $request = $event->getRequest();
            //$requestFile = $request->files->all();
            //$this->logger->info($requestFile["files"][0]->getClientOriginalName());

            $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();

            $tempfile = $event->getFile();


            $parameters = $request->request->all();



        /*  getFile: Get the uploaded file. Is either an instance of Gaufrette\File or Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.
            getRequest: Get the current request including custom variables.
            getResponse: Get the response object to add custom return data.
            getType: Get the name of the mapping of the current upload. Useful if you have multiple mappings and EventListeners.
            getConfig: Get the config of the mapping.
        */


                $parameters = $request->query->all();

                //stock ids to add "new" badges
                $newIds = array();

                    $folder  = $em->getRepository('LibraryBundle:Folder')->find($request->getSession()->get('currentFolder'));
                    $library = $em->getRepository('LibraryBundle:Library')->find($request->getSession()->get('libraryId'));
                //  $this->logger->info('folder: '.$folder->getId());

                    //persit in BDD
                    $file = new File();
                    $file->setLibrary($library);
                    $file->setFolder($folder);

                    $file->setSize($tempfile->getSize());

                    $filenamePart = explode("--", $tempfile->getName());
                    $pathinfo = pathinfo($tempfile->getName());

                    $file->setExtension(strtolower($pathinfo["extension"]));
                    $file->setName($pathinfo['filename']);




                    //check mime type and correct it if docx, xlsx or pptx
                    if(Tools::getMymeTypeFromExt($pathinfo["extension"])){
                        $file->setMimetype(Tools::getMymeTypeFromExt($pathinfo["extension"]));
                    }else{
                        $fi = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
                        $file->setMimetype($fi->buffer($tempfile->getContent()));
                    }

                    $file->setFilename($filenamePart[1]);

                    $em->persist($file);
                    $em->flush();





                    //create thumb
                    if($file->isImage()){
                        $this->logger->info('is an Image');

                        $imagepath = $file->getLocalFileDirectory().$tempfile->getName();
                        $this->logger->info('image path: '.$imagepath);

                        $file->encodeAndMoveFile($imagepath);

                        $this->logger->info('----------------------------------------------------');
                    }else{
                        $this->logger->info('is not an Image');
                        $this->logger->info($file->getLocalFileDirectory().$tempfile->getName());

                        $file->moveTempFile($file->getLocalFileDirectory().$tempfile->getName());
                    }


                    //add id to the New session array
                    if($request->getSession()->get("newfilesids")){
                        $newIds = unserialize($request->getSession()->get("newfilesids"));
                    }
                    $newIds[] = $file->getId();

                    $request->getSession()->set("newfilesids", serialize($newIds));
                    $this->logger->info('JqUploaderFile');

                    $this->logger->info('----------------------------------------------------');

                    /********************************************
                     * 
                     * BUILD RESPONSE
                     * 
                     ******************************************/
                    $this->logger->info('BUILD RESPONSE');
            /*//test1       
                    //create object needed to JqUploader response
                    $responseObjectFile = new JqUploaderFile();
                    $responseObjectFile->setName($file->getFileName());
                    $responseObjectFile->setSize($file->getSize());
                    $responseObjectFile->setUrl($this->router->generate('show_image_link', array('slug'=>$file->getSlug(), 'extension'=>$file->getExtension(), 'size'=>'originals'), true));
                    $responseObjectFile->setThumbnail_url($this->router->generate('show_image_link', array('slug'=>$file->getSlug(), 'extension'=>$file->getExtension(), 'size'=>'thumbnails'), true));
                    $responseObjectFile->setDelete_url($this->router->generate('show_image_link', array('slug'=>$file->getSlug(), 'extension'=>$file->getExtension(), 'size'=>'originals'), true));
                    $responseObjectFile->setDelete_type("DELETE");  
                    $this->logger->info('-------------------------------------------------------');

                    $this->logger->info('ENTITY READY');
            */  

            //test 2        
                    $response = $event->getResponse();
                    $response["file"][]['name'] = $file->getFileName();
                    $response["file"][]['size'] = $file->getSize();
                    $response["file"][]['url'] = $this->router->generate('show_image_link', array('slug'=>$file->getSlug(), 'extension'=>$file->getExtension(), 'size'=>'originals'), true);
                    $response["file"][]['thumbnail_url'] = $this->router->generate('show_image_link', array('slug'=>$file->getSlug(), 'extension'=>$file->getExtension(), 'size'=>'thumbnails'), true);
                    $response["file"][]['delete_url'] = $this->router->generate('show_image_link', array('slug'=>$file->getSlug(), 'extension'=>$file->getExtension(), 'size'=>'originals'), true);
                    $response["file"][]['delete_type'] = "DELETE";


                    return $response;       




        //test 3
        /*
                $jsonResponse = '{"files": [ { "url": '.json_encode($this->router->generate('show_image_link', array('slug'=>$file->getSlug(), 'extension'=>$file->getExtension(), 'size'=>'originals'), true)).',  "thumbnail_url": '.json_encode($this->router->generate('show_image_link', array('slug'=>$file->getSlug(), 'extension'=>$file->getExtension(), 'size'=>'thumbnails'), true)).',  "name": '.json_encode($file->getFileName()).', "type": "'.$file->getMimeType().'", "size": '.$file->getSize().', "delete_url": "http://nourltodelete.com", "delete_type": "DELETE" } ] }';
                return $jsonResponse;

        */          



        }

}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Could you add the error message to the questions body?

Comment: I only see "Error Internal Server Error" below the title of the file.

Comment: And when i tried to follow the suggested method  $response['url'] = $uploadedImage->getUrl(); I Have this in the logs: Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element of Oneup\UploaderBundle\Uploader\Response\EmptyResponse has no effect in /UploadListener.php line 179" at /UploadListener.php line 179

Comment: I'm afraid it's a bit hard to come to a conclusion without access to your `EventListener`. Could you strip it down to the relevant parts and append it to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to devsheeep, here is the solution. 
Really simple when you know it :

```
$response = $event->getResponse();

$files = array();
$files[0] = array(
        'name' => $file->getFileName(),
            'size' => $file->getSize(),
            'url'  => "Your URL",
            'thumbnail_url' => "Your thumb URL",
            'delete_url'   =>"Your delete URL",
            'delete_type' => 'DELETE'
            );
$response['files'] = $files;
```

And we are in an Event context, return values have no effects. Instead we are working with references. So just omit the return statement.

5 to create it, I love.
Thanks again to desheep and the 1up.io team, they are great professionals of the Symfony Framework.